# JQuery DataTables ServerSide autorefresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Hello and sorry for my bad english, but i hope, everyone can understand me what i mean.

I've create in the MySQL Database a table, which is filled with data's (log entries) every seconds. So i've create a html side wiht the JQuery and the Datatables-Plugin to see the entries and i must not login with PhpMyAdmin every time to seen the newest entries.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.datatables.net/favicon.ico">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">

<title>DataTables example - Server-side processing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/jquery.dataTables.css">


 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./js/fnReloadAjax.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#log').DataTable( {
        "bStateSave": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "cache": false,
        "aaSortingFixed": [[4,'desc']],
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sClass": "left" },
            { "sClass": "center" },
            { "sClass": "right" },
            { "sClass": "center" },
            { "sClass": "center" },
            { "sClass": "center" }
        ],
        "ajax": "server_processing.php"
} );

setInterval(function() {otable.fnReloadAjax(null)}, 10000);


} );


</script>

</head>

<body class="dt-example">

<table id="log" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="75%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>TEST A</th>
        <th>TEST B</th>
        <th>TEST C</th>
        <th>TEST D</th>
        <th>TEST E</th>
        <th>TEST F</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>TEST A</th>
        <th>TEST B</th>
        <th>TEST C</th>
        <th>TEST D</th>
        <th>TEST E</th>
        <th>TEST F</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I seen all the datas correct in the grid, but problem is, that the table doesn't auto refresh all 10 seconds ´the table with the new entries from the MySQl Table and i must refresh the side by reload the the page by the browser.

Did any one can help me as beginner in Java, where is the error and which is the correct way? Tank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define your **otable** before you can use it:

For clarification: here's the entire code you should be using - do not call DataTable twice - that will give you an error about duplicate initialization.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var otable = $('#log').DataTable( {
    "bStateSave": true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "cache": false,
    "aaSortingFixed": [[4,'desc']],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sClass": "left" },
        { "sClass": "center" },
        { "sClass": "right" },
        { "sClass": "center" },
        { "sClass": "center" },
        { "sClass": "center" }
    ],
    "ajax": "server_processing.php"
} );

setInterval( function () {
    otable.ajax.reload();
}, 10000 );
});
```

Comment: When i used your shown code example, there was shown nothing, only the table header und table footer.

Comment: thank you very much, i've put the function inside the $(document) and the result is, when i call the page first time, the i become the error message "DataTables warning: table id=log - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3" and when i close the popup, then the table shows all datas and refresh them all 10 seconds.

Comment: do you define your table twice? do you have any other calls to $("#log").DataTable ?

Comment: hello birgit, please seen my used code in the bootom, while he doesn't passed in the cemment field.

Comment: ok, i've found the error and now it work's perfect. Thank you very much for help, Birgit!

Answer (score 0):

Save your DataTable object in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

> do you define your table twice? do you have any other calls to $("#log").DataTable ? –  Birgit Martinelle 29 mins ago

i doesn't understand, what you mean, so this is the used code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">


    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#log').DataTable( {
        "bStateSave": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "cache": false,
        "aaSortingFixed": [[4,'desc']],
        "aoColumns": [
                { "sClass": "center" },
                { "sClass": "center" },
                { "sClass": "center" },
                { "sClass": "center" },
                { "sClass": "center" },
                { "sClass": "center" }
        ],
    "ajax": "server_processing.php"
} );


var otable = $('#log').DataTable( {
"bStateSave": true,
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"cache": false,
"aaSortingFixed": [[4,'desc']],
"aoColumns": [
    { "sClass": "left" },
    { "sClass": "center" },
    { "sClass": "right" },
    { "sClass": "center" },
    { "sClass": "center" },
    { "sClass": "center" }
],
"ajax": "server_processing.php"
} );

setInterval( function () {
otable.ajax.reload();
}, 10000 );


} );
```